# MySQL dynamic query using info from query itself

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I have a query to get product data from WooCommerce. The products have variations (i.e. attributes), and each combination of attributes combined with the base product is its own SKU.  For each SKU, the data are written to the post_meta table with fairly generic keys (e.g. _sku, _price) that have associated values. The exception is the attribute description field, which strangely, its key is based on the base product name itself. This seems unnecessary, since we already would know which base product it's referring to. Nonetheless, that's how it's done.

In my example below, the base product name is 'Ford RAM 1500'.  I'm just doing a single variation for testing and the attribute is 'trailer', which specifies the trailer type that goes with the truck. The trailer type can be 'no trailer','hitch-2in','hitch-2.5in','hitch-3in'. It then creates a key in the Post_Meta table called 'attribute_ford_ram_1500' and will assign a description to the meta_value, such as "hitch-2in $25,269" - the variation item and the total price including that variation.

Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT p.ID,
p.post_title 'name',  -- Ford RAM 1500
p.post_content 'description',
GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name SEPARATOR ' | ') 'Category',
MAX(CASE WHEN meta.meta_key = '_sku' THEN meta.meta_value END) 'SKU',
MAX(CASE WHEN meta.meta_key = 'attribute_trailer' THEN meta.meta_value END) 'Trailer',  -- Trailer type added to product, or none
MAX(CASE WHEN meta.meta_key = 'attribute_ford_ram_1500' THEN meta.meta_value END) 'Var_Description',  -- Ford RAM 1500 is from the p.post_title (name) field above
MAX(CASE WHEN meta.meta_key = '_price' THEN meta.meta_value END) 'Price',
MAX(CASE WHEN meta.meta_key = '_weight' THEN meta.meta_value END) 'Weight',
MAX(CASE WHEN meta.meta_key = '_stock' THEN meta.meta_value END) 'Stock'
FROM wp_posts AS p
JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta ON p.ID = meta.post_ID
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT pp.id,
GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ' > ') AS name
FROM wp_posts AS pp
JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON pp.id = tr.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
|| tt.parent = t.term_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
GROUP BY pp.id, tt.term_id
) cat ON p.id = cat.id
WHERE (p.post_type = 'product' OR p.post_type = 'product_variation')
AND meta.meta_key IN ('_sku', '_price', '_weight', '_stock','attribute_foundation','attribute_ford_ram_1500')  -- Would need to dynamically change the last attribute based on the p.post_title (name) field
AND meta.meta_value is not null
GROUP BY p.ID
) d
WHERE d.SKU IS NOT NULL
```

This works fine - for one base product. But let's say there's also Ford RAM 2500 product. For it's variations, there won't be a meta.meta_key = 'attributes_ford_ram_1500'; instead it will be meta.meta_key = 'attributes_ford_ram_2500'.  I'm assuming I'd need to do something more dynamic. So my question is, how can I make my query find the correct meta_key name based on the post_title (name) in that result row?

Comment: pro tip: don't use single quotes around identifiers (i.e. column names) if an identifier needs to be escaped, enclose it in backticks.  also consider including the optional `AS` keyword for column aliases. reserve single quotes for enclosing string literals.  wrangling an EAV model back into a standard relational representation, using SQL, can get ugly complex. Earmarking this question as a future "how can i abuse EAV" reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to form the meta_key with an expression instead of hard-coding it:

```
...
MAX(CASE WHEN meta.meta_key = CONCAT('attribute_', 
    REPLACE(p.post_title, ' ', '_')) 
  THEN meta.meta_value END) AS `Var_Description`,
...
```

Remember you have to use `p.post_title` because you can't refer to an alias in the same select-list where the alias is defined.

Comment: Working fiddle to show equivalent solution I arrived at: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pqeBERS3vLG9AfzWm8ZTrY/1

Comment: If you are using a case-insensitive collation, you shouldn't need to use `lower()` but it won't do any harm.

Comment: Excellent - both of you.  Just had to fix the REPLACE to use hyphen instead of underscore.  Then added the same concat ```concat('attribute_', replace(lower(p.post_title),' ','-'))``` to update the WHERE clause at the bottom.  All good now.